# Create dropdownlist based on selected dropdownlist from master page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, master-pages

I have masterpage & content page. In master Page I have DropDownList of Cities which Gets cities from database. And in my content page I DropDownList Of Areas which also comes from database. Now Suppose If My city gets changed then desire area related to that particular selected city should also get changed. I have manage my db tables properly & passing correct query as well. But DropDownList Of areas doesn't gets refreshed if City DropDownList gets changed. Following code I am trying.

MasterPage

```
Private Sub MasterPage_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Me.PopulateCities()
        If Not IsPostBack Then
            If Session("masterLocation") Is Nothing Then
                Session("cityName") = "Pune"
            Else
                locationSelector.Text = Session("masterLocation").ToString()
            End If
        End If
        locationPopupActivator.Text = locationSelector.SelectedValue.ToString
    End Sub

Private Sub PopulateCities()
        Using conn As New MySqlConnection()
            conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager _
                .ConnectionStrings("conio").ConnectionString()
            Using cmd As New MySqlCommand()
                cmd.CommandText = "Select cityName from cities where status = 'active' order by cityName"
                cmd.Connection = conn
                conn.Open()
                Using sdr As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                    While sdr.Read()
                        Dim item As New ListItem()
                        item.Text = sdr("cityName").ToString()
                        item.Value = sdr("cityName").ToString()
                        'item.Selected = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr("IsSelected"))
                        locationSelector.Items.Add(item)
                    End While
                End Using
                conn.Close()
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub
```

ContentPage

```
Private Sub hospitals_PreRender(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.PreRender
If Not IsPostBack Then
      Me.PopulateAreas()
End If
End Sub

Private Sub PopulateAreas()
        areasList.Items.Clear()
        Dim citySelector As RadioButtonList = Page.Master.FindControl("locationSelector")
        Using conn As New MySqlConnection()
            conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager _
                .ConnectionStrings("conio").ConnectionString()
            Using cmd As New MySqlCommand()
                cmd.CommandText = "Select * from areas where areaCity like '" + citySelector.SelectedItem.ToString + "%'"
                cmd.Connection = conn
                conn.Open()
                Using sdr As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                    While sdr.Read()
                        Dim item As New ListItem()
                        item.Text = sdr("areaName").ToString()
                        item.Value = sdr("areaName").ToString()
                        'item.Selected = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr("IsSelected"))
                        areasList.Items.Add(item)
                    End While
                End Using
                conn.Close()
            End Using
        End Using
        areasList.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("All Area", "All"))
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything in your code is fine just make changes On Pre_Render event of your content page

```
If IsPostBack Then
    Me.PopulateAreas()
End If
```

Make this changes. Hope this will solve your problem.